# How to package python and kivy application for Raspbian Buster

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, kivy, raspbian, kivy-language

I am currently writing an application for a raspberry pi 3 using python3.7 and kivy1.11.1. I am trying to package a test application to ensure that it will work. I have created a simple grid with 6 buttons. When you click on a button it prints "button pressed" to the screen. I am using a separate kv file to lay this out as this will be more practical as the application develops. So I have two files, "test.py" and "Test.kv".

I have been using pyinstaller to package my app but it is not working. It runs and creates the executable file just fine with no errors. I then drag my executable file out to my main folder from the "dist" folder as recommended [in this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UZX5kH72Yx4&t=243s).

My command is:

```
pyinstaller --onefile --add-data "Test.kv:." test.py
```

I have also tried:

```
pyinstaller --onedir --add-data "Test.kv:." test.py
```

which does the same: blank window no widgets, no errors.

When I try to execute it nothing happens. I don't know what is wrong because I'm not getting any errors when I try to execute it from the terminal. When I do the exact same process on windows it works so its not the code. On occasion, I think it does eventually run but I just get a blank screen and again no error. This would leave me to believe it's an issue with reading the .kv file.

Perhaps this process doesn't work with kivy and I need to use some other method to package my application. However I have also tried [this kind of approach](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a9GzDZB5VeU) but it has left me with errors. I much prefer the pyinstaller method however I don't know if it is going to work as it doesn't seem to pick up the .kv file.

Any help/advice on this issue would be greatly appreciated?

My test.spec file:

```
# -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-

block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(['test.py'],
             pathex=['/home/pi/Desktop/WinTest'],
             binaries=[],
             datas=[('Test.kv', '.')],
             hiddenimports=[],
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher,
             noarchive=False)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          a.binaries,
          a.zipfiles,
          a.datas,
          [],
          name='test',
          debug=False,
          bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          upx_exclude=[],
          runtime_tmpdir=None,
          console=False )
```

The following picture is my program folder (sorry for the poor quality). My library files are in venv/Lib/site-packages. This is where my kivy/kivy_deps folders are. Could the issue be that the program can't find my library files? But surely if that was the issue it would throw a "file not found" error? And as previously stated, I am not receiving any errors.

[image: My Program Folder]

Found this in my warn-text.txt file

```
missing module named kivy.lib.vidcore_lite.egl - imported by kivy.lib.vidcore_lite (top-level), kivy.core.window.window_egl_rpi (top-level)
missing module named kivy.lib.vidcore_lite.bcm - imported by kivy.lib.vidcore_lite (top-level), kivy.core.window.window_egl_rpi (top-level)
```

Comment: I believe that in order to build a package for a specific OS, you need to run `Pyinstaller` on that OS.

Comment: Thank you John, I should have made that clear. I am however running pyinstaller on the raspberry pi.

Comment: In your `spec` file, you need to include your `.kv` files in the `datas` list.

Comment: Thanks for your reply John. I have double checked my spec file and have added the contents to my question for your viewing. As I'm sure you will see yourself the Test.kv file is in the datas list. Perhaps there is something else I need to add to this file? Unfortunately the Kivy docs don't cover packaging for this platform.

Comment: Again, since you have not posted your code, I can only guess. But if you are not loading your `kv` file explicitly, then the file is incorrectly named. It should be `test.kv`, not `Test.kv` (again making the assumption that your app is named something like `TestApp`).

Comment: Also, note a common misconception about `Pyinstaller`. When you invoke `Pyinstaller` with a `py` file as the argument, any `spec` file is ignored and overwritten. And when you invoke `Pyinstaller` with a `spec` file argument, then almost all command line options are ignored.

Comment: My app is named `TestApp()` and in following a tutorial it says to name your `.kv` file `Test.kv`. It works perfectly no matter what way I run it on Windows. Now for Raspberry Pi I changed my file name to `test.kv` and deleted my .spec file and reinstalled everything and it now works. Thanks again for your suggestions!

Comment: It works on `Windows` because on `Windows`  file names are case independent.